# How to get package manager information for linux from browser

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I want to get Linux package manager(deb, rpm, etc.)information from the web browser using Javascript. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Browsers running on Linux can provide no information about system package manager state.

Comment: I thought if I got distro name like  'ubuntu,' 'fedora,' etc. from the browser, it's enough to find the package manager with basic mapping. But can I get the distro name from the browser?

Comment: It would help if you would describe what exactly it is you want to do.